# No puedo realizar login con spring security

Tags: java, autenticación, spring-security

Actualizado: 18-04-2022
Hola a todos, desde ya agradezco su ayuda. Tengo un examen para generar un sistema donde los usuarios pueden agregar sus shows favoritos y rankearlos. Estoy tratando de buscar y entender porque mi aplicación no loguea, el error que indica via consola es el siguiente:

org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: cl.desafiolatam.examen.model.Users.roles, could not initialize proxy - no Session

Adjunto los codigos revelevantes

login.jsp:

```
<h1>Login</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="/login">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Emailaddress</label> 
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="username" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="username">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label> 
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" /> 
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login" />
    </form>
```

UserController:

```
@GetMapping("/login")
public String loginForm(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error, @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false)
String logout, Model model, @Valid @ModelAttribute("user") Users users, BindingResult result) {
    //NOTA IMPORTANTE: Al parecer no me llega data del form, al tratar de instanciar user.getUsername por ejemplo, sale null, lo mismo si trato de usar un objeto session http. Lo que me complica, es que acorde a lo que he estudiado, no deberia manejar el acceso con un POST, no al menos en spring security
    if (error != null) {
        model.addAttribute("errorMessage", "Credenciales invalidas, intente nuevamente");
    }
    if (logout != null) {
        model.addAttribute("logoutMessage", "Login exitoso!");  
    }
    return "login";
    
}
```

UserService.java:

```
@Service
public class UserService {
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;
@Autowired
private RoleRepository roleRepository;
@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

// Create
public void saveWithUserRole(Users users) {
    users.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(users.getPassword()));
    users.setRoles(roleRepository.findByName("ROLE_USER"));
    userRepository.save(users);
}

public void saveUserWithAdminRole(Users users) {
    users.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(users.getPassword()));
    users.setRoles(roleRepository.findByName("ROLE_ADMIN"));
    userRepository.save(users);
}

// READ ONE
public Users findByUsername(String username) {
    return userRepository.findByUsername(username);
}

public Users findUserById(Integer id) {
    Optional<Users> optionalUser = userRepository.findById(id);
    if (optionalUser.isPresent()) {
        return optionalUser.get();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public Users findUserByEmail(String email) {
    return userRepository.findUserByEmail(email);
}

public List<Users> findAllUsers() {
    return userRepository.findAll();
}

// create
public void createUser(Users users) {
    users.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(users.getPassword()));
    userRepository.save(users);
}
// update
public void updateUser(Users users) {
    userRepository.save(users);
}
// delete
public void deleteUser(Integer id) {
    userRepository.deleteById(id);
}
```

UserDetailsServiceImplementation.java:

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImplementation implements UserDetailsService {
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    /*
     * Nota: dejo esta linea por si debo modificar el software en el futuro y
     * agregar administradores Users user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
     */
    Users users = userRepository.findUserByEmail(username);
    if (users == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Users not found");
    }
    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(users.getEmail(), 
    users.getPassword(),getAuthorities(users));
}

private List<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Users user) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    // authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
    for (Role role : user.getRoles()) {
        GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName());
        authorities.add(grantedAuthority);
    }
    return authorities;
}
```

WebSecurityConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = false)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/registration").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    .anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/home", true).permitAll().and().logout().permitAll();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
}
}
```

User.java (modelo):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
private Integer id;
@Size(min = 3, message = "Username must be present")
private String username;
@Size(min = 5, message = "Email must be greater present and in a valid format")
private String email;
@Size(min = 8 ,message="Password must be greater than 8characters")
private String password;
@Transient
private String passwordConfirmation;

public Users() {
}

// RELACIONES
// 1:N SHOW
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "creatorShow", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
List<Show> userShows;

// 1:N RATING
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "users", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Rating> ratings;


// ROLES
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "users_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
private List<Role> roles;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}


public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}


public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}


public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}


public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}


public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}


public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}


public String getPasswordConfirmation() {
    return passwordConfirmation;
}


public void setPasswordConfirmation(String passwordConfirmation) {
    this.passwordConfirmation = passwordConfirmation;
}


public List<Show> getUserShows() {
    return userShows;
}


public void setUserShows(List<Show> userShows) {
    this.userShows = userShows;
}


public List<Rating> getRatings() {
    return ratings;
}


public void setRatings(List<Rating> ratings) {
    this.ratings = ratings;
}


public List<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}


public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}
}
```

Quedo atento a vuestra ayuda, necesito presentar este examen el viernes 22/04/2022 a más tardar y no encuentro solución a mi problema, según yo, todo esta bien construido. Desde ya, muchas gracias

Comment: Prueba cambiando `FetchType.LAZY` en `// ROLES
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` por `FetchType.EAGER` y comenta si se arregla el problema.

Comment: En el JSP defines un formulario que usa get para logarte, pero en el método loginForm no veo que hagas nada con el usuario recibido

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez, fue una de las primeras opciones que probé y se cae al tratar de levantarlo:
 Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags: cl.desafiolatam.examen.model.User.ratings, ...model.User.roles

Comment: @PabloLozano cambie el form del login con etiquetas form normales, acorde a lo que he estudiado, eso bastaría. Otro problema es que al parecer no estoy recibiendo nada justamente del form jsp login.

Comment: ahi actualice el codigo que he cambiado con fecha 18-04-2022

Comment: ¿Tienes un repo que se pueda clonar? _"Lo que me complica, es que acorde a lo que he estudiado, no deberia manejar el acceso con un POST"_ Pues me parece que es TODO LO CONTRARIO. Con GET la información del usuario va cruda en la URL. Los formularios siempre deben ir con POST, sobretodo si llevan información sensible.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez, agradezco la ayuda, pero lo he resuelto, no usando la solución mas empirica, pero al menos ahora hace match y login. Sin embargo, se me está presentando otro problema, pero creo que corresponde ya a otro hilo. Muchas gracias a todos por sus sugerencias y apoyo!!

Answer (score 1):

Encontre una solución que es medio parche, en el application.properties, deben agregar la siguiente linea:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
```